# Communication between two daemons running in two different dockers/containers

Tags: docker, sockets, containers, ipc, virtualization

I have two dockers which runs two different daemons/applications. There should be a communication between these two daemons/applications such that:

a) The application/daemon running in docker 1 should be able to send a command on a socket on which application/daemon running in docker 2 will be listening.

b) The application/daemon running in docker 1 produces a data in a mmap file which should be mmapped by application/daemon running in docker 2.

## My approach

1) I tried sharing a file system between these two containerized applications/daemons, where the socket file will be present and shared mmap file also is present. Things seem to be working fine with this.

Are there any other design approaches available to solve this?

-Ram